Models with Interaction effect in R - "*" versus ":"
I'm trying to form a model with an interaction effect. My data is related to plant species, the number of flowers the plant produces and the number of pollinators.
Using my uni notes my code looks like this:
res.aov3 <- aov(NumberofPollinator ~ NumberofFlowers * Species, data = searocket_plant)
res.aov3 <- aov(NumberofPollinator ~ NumberofFlowers + Species + NumberofFlowers:Species, data = searocket_plant)
summary(res.aov3)

But I'm not sure what the difference between * and : is, how do my first two lines of code differ?
I need to determine first if there is an effect of flower number or species, and then determine if there is an interaction between the terms. But I'm lost on the syntax
res.aov2 <- aov(NumberofPollinator ~ NumberofFlowers + Species, data = searocket_plant)

res.aov3 <- aov(NumberofPollinator ~ NumberofFlowers * Species, data = searocket_plant)
res.aov3 <- aov(NumberofPollinator ~ NumberofFlowers + Species + NumberofFlowers:Species, data = searocket_plant)

#Then to test whether interaction is significant
#Model without interaction, ie. additive model
add_model <- aov(NumberofPollinator ~ NumberofFlowers + Species, data = searocket_plant)
#Model with interaction
interaction_model <- aov(NumberofPollinator ~ NumberofFlowers * Species, data = searocket_plant)

Do I have the right idea? I'm still lost on * versus :

a * b is just shorthand for a + b + a : b. Read help("formula").
